# awk regex magic (match first occurrence of character in each line)

Tags: regex, bash, apache, awk, sed

Have been scratching my head over this one, hoping there's a simple solution that I've missed.

**Summary**

Simplified the following code can't cope with IPv6 addresses in the (here abbreviated) apache log parsed to it. Do I SED the variable before parsing to AWK or can I change the AWK regex to match only the first ":" on each line in $clog?

```
$ clog='djerk.nl:80 200.87.62.227 - - [20/Nov/2015:01:06:25 +0100] "GET /some_url HTTP/1.1" 404 37252
bogus.com:80 200.87.62.227 - - [20/Nov/2015:01:06:27 +0100] "GET /some_url HTTP/1.1" 404 37262
djerk.nl:80 200.87.62.227 - - [20/Nov/2015:01:06:29 +0100] "GET /another_url HTTP/1.1" 200 11142
ipv6.com:80 2a01:3e8:abcd:320::1 - - [20/Nov/2015:01:35:24 +0100] "GET /some_url HTTP/1.1" 200 273'

$ echo "$clog" | awk -F '[: -]+' '{ vHost[$1]+=$13 } END { for (var in vHost) { printf "%s %.0f\n", var, vHost[var] }}'
> bogus.com 37262
> djerk.nl 48394
> ipv6.com 0
```

As can be seen the last line of variable $clog, the vhost domain is caught but not the byte count which should come out at 273 instead of 0.

**Original long question**

The problem I have is with the ":" character. In addition to the other two characters (space and dash), I need AWK to match only the first occurrence of ":" in each line it's evaluating. the following splits each line by three characters which works fine, until the log entries contain IPv6 addresses.

```
matrix=$( echo "$clog" | awk -F '[: -]+' '{ vHost[$1]++; Bytes[$1]+=$13 } END { for (var in vHost) { printf "%s %.0f %.0f\n", var, vHost[var], Bytes[var] }}' )
```

The above code converts the following log entries (contained in variable $clog):

```
djerk.nl:80 200.87.62.227 - - [20/Nov/2015:01:06:25 +0100] "GET /some_url HTTP/1.1" 404 37252 "-" "Safari/11601.1.56 CFNetwork/760.0.5 Darwin/15.0.0 (x86_64)"
bogus.com:80 200.87.62.227 - - [20/Nov/2015:01:06:27 +0100] "GET /some_url HTTP/1.1" 404 37262 "-" "Safari/11601.1.56 CFNetwork/760.0.5 Darwin/15.0.0 (x86_64)"
djerk.nl:80 200.87.62.227 - - [20/Nov/2015:01:06:29 +0100] "GET /wordpress/2014/ssl-intercept-headaches HTTP/1.1" 200 11142 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B410 Safari/600.1.4"
djerk.nl:80 200.87.62.227 - - [20/Nov/2015:01:06:30 +0100] "GET /some_other_url HTTP/1.1" 404 37264 "-" "Safari/11601.1.56 CFNetwork/760.0.5 Darwin/15.0.0 (x86_64)"
```

Into a table like so, containing vhost name (sans TCP port number), hits and cumulative byte count. One line per vhost:

```
djerk.nl 3 85658
bogus.com 1 37262
```

But IPv6 addresses get unintentionally split due to their notation and this causes AWK to produce bogus output when evaluation these log entries. Sample IPv6 log entry:

```
djerk.nl:80 2a01:3e8:abcd:320::1 - - [20/Nov/2015:01:35:24 +0100] "POST /wordpress/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=*** HTTP/1.0" 200 273 "-" "WordPress; http://www.djerk.nl/wordpress"
```

I guess a work around would be to mangle variable $clog to replace the first occurrence of ":" and remove this character from the AWK regex. But I don't think native bash substitution is capable of negotiating variables with multiple lines.

```
clog=$(sed 's/:/ /' <<< "$clog")
matrix=$( echo "$clog" | awk -F '[ -]+' '{ vHost[$1]++; Bytes[$1]+=$10 } END { for (var in vHost) { printf "%s %.0f %.0f\n", var, vHost[var], Bytes[var] }}' )
```

This works because $clog is quoted which preserves the line feeds and runs sed on each line individually. As a result (and shown) the AWK line needs to be adjusted to ignore ":" and grab $10 instead of $13 for the byte count.

So as it turns out, in writing this, I've already given myself a solution. But I'm sure someone will know of a better more efficient way.

Comment: Is there any way you can simplify this to something easy for us to understand but which you can then adapt the solution of to your real problem? There's just WAY too much text above for me to wade through it to try to understand it all and i suspect others will feel the same.

Comment: If you `print $1,$13` on each line, you'll see that problems arise even without the IPv6 address.

Comment: Capturing the log file in a variable before extracting looks suspicious.  Usually you would want to run Awk on a stream of bytes from a file or a socket, not on a variable you capture.

Comment: @EdMorton Summary added, thank you for pushing me to simplify the actual question asked.

Comment: @hek2mgl Not as far as I can tell. Admittedly I'm assuming spaces in URLs to show up as "%20". Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @tripleee Thank you for your input. The reason for not going direct to the log file is that previous to this command some other code extracts the last 5 minutes of logs from the standard Apache log file other_vhosts_access.log. Would you suggest adding a bespoke Apache log file with it's own 5 minute rotation in "/etc/logrotate.d/apache2"? I hadn't considered this but it would definitely reduce the size of my script. The question regarding IPv6 addresses remains though, even when reading direct from file.

Comment: Keeping large amounts of data in memory scares me, but if you know you have enough RAM to do that, perhaps just ignore me.  I would extract the last five minutes to a temporary file if you cannot make it a pipeline.

Comment: The "obvious" apparently alluded to in @hek2mgl's comment is that the byte count will not be in `$13` when the URL contains dashes.

Comment: Thank you kindly on both accounts! Your answer provided works beautifully. Next up is simplification by adjusting the apache logrotate rather than burning CPU cycles munching through many a MB of data every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't split the entire line on colons.  Remove the port number from the field you extract instead.

```
split($1, v, /:/); vHost[v[1]]++; ...
```

I don't see why you would split on dashes, either; either way, the field numbers will be renumbered, so you would end up with something like

```
awk '{ split($1, v, /:/); vHost[v[1]]++; Bytes[v[1]]+=$11 }
   END { for (var in vHost)
        printf "%s %.0f %.0f\n", var, vHost[var], Bytes[var] }'
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! Wasn't aware that was possible. Resulting code for the summary I added `echo "$clog" | awk '{ split($1, v, /:/); vHost[v[1]]+=$11 } END { for (var in vHost) { printf "%s %.0f\n", var, vHost[var] }}'`

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to stop worrying about `IPv4` vs. `IPv6` and simply make `FS` flexible enough to handle it without splitting an extra array `v` :

```
mawk 'END { for (_ in __)
                printf("%s %d\n", _, __[_]) } { __[$!_] += $NF }' FS=':.* '
```

---

```
ipv6.com 273
djerk.nl 48394
bogus.com 37262
```

to make the `regex` more resilient to an extra double-quoted string at the tail, try modifying `RS` :

---

```
gawk 'END { for (_ in __) printf("%s %d\n", _, __[_]) 

        } { __[$!_] += $NF }' FS=':.+ ' RS='([^0-9]*"[^"]*")?\n'
```